# How to call \enquote by pressing only one time " key in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, auctex, csquotes

I'm using `\enquote` command of `csquotes` package to handle (multilingual) quotations.

With Emacs+AUCTeX, I use the three following lines (in .emacs) to be able to call `\enquote` command by pressing to <kbd>"</kbd> twice.

```
 '(LaTeX-csquotes-close-quote "}")
 '(LaTeX-csquotes-open-quote "\\enquote{")
 '(LaTeX-csquotes-quote-after-quote t)
```

Indeed, the LaTeX-csquotes-quote-after-quote option creates this shortcut. (Here is more information about it from [AUCTex Documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Quotes.html)).

> User Option: TeX-quote-after-quote
>
> Determines the behavior of ". If it is non-nil, typing " will insert a literal double quote. The respective values of TeX-open-quote
>   and TeX-close-quote will be inserted after typing " **once again**.
>
> [...]
>
> **In case you are using the ‘csquotes’ package, you should customize
>   LaTeX-csquotes-open-quote, LaTeX-csquotes-close-quote and
>   LaTeX-csquotes-quote-after-quote. The quotation characters will only
>   be used if both variables—LaTeX-csquotes-open-quote and
>   LaTeX-csquotes-close-quote—are non-empty strings. But then the
>   ‘csquotes’-related values will take precedence over the
>   language-specific ones.**

So, if I press once <kbd>"</kbd> I obtain `"`, if I press twice I obtain `\enquote{`. I can close the quotation by pressing again twice <kbd>"</kbd> which produces `}`.

However, I use `\enquote` a lot and never `"`. Therefore, I would like to change the default behavior of `cquostes.el` by inversing this order.

My goal is to have `\enquote{` and `}` when pressing **only one time** <kbd>"</kbd>. I would also be able to call `"` be pressing **twice** <kbd>"</kbd>.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is very silly.

I shouldn't activate the LaTeX-csquotes-quote-after-quote option... I was wrong (in my question): the LaTeX-csquotes-quote-after-quote option **does not** create the shortcut but introduces the "pressing twice" thing.

Removing this line (or set it to false or nil) fixes the issue:

```
'(LaTeX-csquotes-quote-after-quote t)
```

Comment: So how are you getting `"` then?

Comment: @StephanLehmke Pressing once `"` calls `\enquote{` and twice gets normal `"`.